# JavaScript setInterval() unexplained behavior

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to write a small side project.
In this project I am trying to navigate to a certain HTML page, select a couple of buttons, lines and checkboxes and then submit my selection.

I want my main function to be called each X seconds in order to search for new lines; for this I am using setInterval()

The thing is, each time the function is called, inly part of it getting executed no matter how much milliseconds I pass to setInterval() as a parameter.

My "main" code is:

```
var counter = setInterval(function() {
  if (window.lev_script_on) {
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("mainGrid-refresh-btn")[0];
    var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("x-grid-view")[0];
    var table = document.getElementsByClassName("x-grid-item")

    //btn.click()
    //console.log("clicked refresh")
    var currProjects = grid.childNodes[1].childElementCount + grid.childNodes[0].childElementCount;
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("x-grid-row")[0]
    //window.alert(rows.cells[0].innerText)

    for (let i = 0; i < currProjects; i++) {
      rows = document.getElementsByClassName("x-grid-row")[i]
      var ID = rows.cells[0].innerText
      var Name = rows.cells[1].innerText
      window.alert(ID)
      window.alert(Name)
      // Name.includes("testing") || 
      if (Name.includes("AAA") || Name.includes("BBB") || Name.includes("CCC")) {
        var line_click = table[i].setAttribute("class", "x-grid-item x-grid-item-over x-grid-item-selected")
        rows.setAttribute("aria-selected", true);
        rows.cells[0].setAttribute("class", "x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1226 x-grid-cell-first x-grid-item-focused")
        rows.cells[0].click()
        rows.cells[1].click()


        var select_btn = document.getElementsByClassName("x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-large")[0];
        select_btn.click()

        var accept_check = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-pdSubmissionBudgetJobInfoColumnRadioAccept-"]')[0]
        var data = accept_check.getAttribute("data-columnid")

        var radio_button = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="x-grid-radio-col x-grid-cc-pdSubmissionBudgetJobInfoColumnRadioAccept-"]')[0]
        radio_button.setAttribute("class", "x-grid-radio-col-on")
        radio_button.click()
        radio_button.clicked = true

        var new_button_class = "x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-" + data + " groupUnderline x-grid-cell-checkcolumn x-grid-dirty-cell x-unselectable x-grid-item-focused"
        accept_check.setAttribute("class", new_button_class)
        accept_check.click()

        var agree_box = document.getElementsByClassName("x-form-cb-input x-hidden-clip")[0]
        agree_box.setAttribute("aria-checked", true)
        agree_box.click()

        var submit_but = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small"]')[1]
        submit_but.click()


        // In case the project was already taken, close the "Error" window
        var close_btn = document.getElementsByClassName("x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-btn-over")
        if (close_btn) {
          close_btn.click()
        }

        btn.click()
        console.log("clicked refresh")
      }
    }

  }
}, 1000);
```

The thing is instead of running the whole function during execution, only part of it is being run each time (each X seconds). what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: When you click the submit button, the form is submitted and the page is reloaded.

Comment: The problem is that the code reaches the submit button only after 1000*5 executions and not in a single execution. why is that?

Comment: Any errors in the console?